# Refresh label every second

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I try to make a refresh for a label every second in swift 3.
I alway get the following error:

```
Showing Recent Issues
Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
```

This is the Code I've used:

```
    var TimerBeacon = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, 
selector: Selector(("Timer")), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


        func Timer() {
             //here is the label to refresh
         }
```

I hope someone could help me :)

Comment: Bad idea: `Timer` is a reserved word (a struct) in Swift 3. Rename your selector at least with something starting with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1,
                             target: self,
                             selector: #selector(yourMethodName),
                             userInfo: nil,
                             repeats: true)          

Use above code. T\It will run. Be remeber you have to create a method

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your code isn't updated for Swift 3, and could use some better naming conventions.

Create the timer:

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

This is the function that the timer will call every second:

```
func update() {
    // here is the label to refresh
}
```

When you want to stop the timer, call `invalidate()`:

```
timer.invalidate()
```

Comment: Also need to add: timer.fire()

Comment: @BhavukJain No, that's not true. Calling the `scheduledTimer` method on `Timer` automatically starts the timer. I just verified this in a new project.

Comment: @BhavukJain `timer.fire()` is not needed unless the selector is supposed to be called **immediately** rather than after the scheduled interval.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the same without timer. Use the following code

```
var iteration = 0
func updateLabel() {
    iteration = iteration == Int.max ? 0 : (iteration + 1)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
            self.label.text = "\(self.iteration)"
            self.updateLabel()
        })

    }
}
```

Note that I have taken `iteration` just for example. You can update the label the way you want.